# Partial Derivative Being Treated As Full Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative, differential-forms, chain-rule

In this Khan Academy video (https://youtu.be/YT6XwkcPcsw?t=138), Sal takes partial derivatives of several dependent variables.

When taking the full derivative of $Q(x,\ y,\ z(x,\ y))$ with respect to $x$, one must sum all paths through variable dependencies which lead to $x$, yielding $\frac{dQ}{dx} = \frac{∂Q}{∂x} + \frac{∂Q}{∂z}\frac{dz}{dx}$.  However, the video treats partial derivatives in the same way that one normally treats full derivatives, contrary to my prior understanding.  In fact, the partial derivative $\frac{∂Q}{∂x}$ appears in the formula for the full derivative $\frac{dQ}{dx}$, so when the same formula is applied to partial derivatives, it looks like he is saying, $\frac{∂Q}{∂x} = \frac{∂Q}{∂x} + \frac{∂Q}{∂z}\frac{dz}{dx}$, which is nonsense if $Q$ depends on $z$ nontrivially.  What is going on here?

Comment: On the lhs you regard $Q$ as a function of $x$ only, that is $Q'(x) = Q(x, y(x), z(x, y(x)))$. Idk whether that qualifies as abuse of notation though.

Comment: Once again, a common abuse of notation leads to the same confusion: The function called $Q$ on the left side of the equation is not the same function as the one called $Q$ on the right side.

Comment: But it seems right that he's taking the partial derivative, since the partial derivative operator comes straight from Green's Theorem.  Also, why would the multivariable chain rule even be necessary if $Q$ is regarded as a function of a single variable?